# sort large data in redis

Tags: sorting, redis

how to sort large data in redis?

Answer (score 3):

What kind of data?

In Redis, it makes more sense to store the data in the order you want to retrieve it.

Depending on your use case you may want to look at [lists](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/Lists) or [sorted sets](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/SortedSets).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ZADD` and `ZRANGE` commands for this:

```
redis> zadd mySet 1 "Large data 1"
(integer) 1
redis> zadd mySet 3 "Large data 3"
(integer) 1
redis> zadd mySet 2 "Large data 2"
(integer) 1
redis> zrange mySet 0 -1
1) "Large data 1"
2) "Large data 2"
3) "Large data 3"
```